# Proper isotopy of proper embeddings of manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

We know from Theorem 2.2 in(http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Embeddings_of_manifolds_with_boundary:_classification#6.2) that

1. Any two smooth embeddings of closed oriented $n$-manifold(n>1) in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ are isotopic.
2. Any two smooth embeddings of compact oriented $n$-manifold(n>1) with nonempty boundary in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ are isotopic.

Question: when does any two proper embeddings of compact manifold with boundary in a $k$-disc $D^k$ are properly isotopic?

Kindly provide the reference.

Thanks advance.

Comment: Your question has an error in it.  There are embeddings $S^1 \to \Bbb R^3$ that are not isotopic.  I think you need to use $\Bbb R^{2n+2}$ to get a true statement.  The statement for manifolds with boundary is basically the same as for manifolds without boundary, you need the dimension of the disc to be at least as large as $2n+2$.  Similarly, you need the dimension of the boundary of the disc to be at least as big as $2(n-1)+2 = 2n$, but this comes for free from the previous condition.  i.e. this kind of problem you handle in two steps, first the boundary, then the interior.

Comment: Your statement  (1) is also not true for $n=0$, i.e. there are non-isotopic embeddings $S^0 \to \Bbb R$.  It looks like you failed to mention you are only considering the high-dimensional case.  The mpim reference mentions these conditions.  The theorems I'm citing follow from the weak Whitney embedding theorem, while the mpim reference is that plus what they are calling the "Whitney-Wu unknotting theorem".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have corrected the results.